# How to load a Bitmap in LAB color space?

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, color-space, lab-color-space

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
```

This line loads an image in RGB. What about a LAB colors? 
I found `ColorSpace.Model.LAB` constant but not how to use it.